# Ember js: Multiply two numbers to get total

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Building a mini quoting application.
Not using Ember data or anything else right now, just trying to work with the raw data.

Can't seem to multiply two numbers together to get a total for a specific item. Trying to multiply the rate and hours together to get the items total amount.

My quote controller and item controller:

```
Quoter.QuoteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    addSection: function(){
        var sectionTitle = "Section 3"
        var new_section = {sectionTitle: sectionTitle, items: []};
        quote.sections.pushObject(new_section);
    },
    addItem: function(section){
        var name = "Item"
        var hours = 20
        var total = 100
        var new_item = {title: name, hours: hours, total: total};
        section.items.pushObject(new_item);
    },
    pmRatio: function(){
        ratio = this.get('ratio');

    },
    removeSection: function(section){
    quote.sections.removeObject(section);
},
    removeItem: function(section, item){
    section.items.removeObject(item);
},
}
```

});

```
Quoter.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["quote"],
    getTotal: function(item) {
        return this.get('rate') * this.get('item.hours')
    }.observes('rate', 'item.hours'),
})
```

My data:

```
var quote =
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Project",
    customer: "Customer",
    rate: 105,
    pm_ratio: 0.2,
    sections: [
    {
        sectionTitle: "Section 1",
        items: [
        {
            title: "Item 1",
            hours: 10,
            total: 100
        },
        {
            title: "Item 2",
            hours: 6,
            total: 100

        }]
    },
    {
        sectionTitle: "Section 2",
        items: [
        {
            title: "Item 1",
            hours: 10,
            total: 100

        },
        {
            title: "Item 2",
            hours: 6,
            total: 100
        }]
    }]
}
```

My template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="quote">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Quote</h1>


    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    {{input id="title" class="form-control" value=title placeholder="Add Project Title"}}

    <h3>{{customer}}</h3>
    {{input id="customer" class="form-control" value=customer placeholder="Add Customer"}}

    <label for="rate">Hourly Rate:</label> 
      {{input type="text" id="rate" class="form-control" value=rate}}

    <label for="ratio">Project Management Ratio:</label> 
    {{input type="text" id="ratio" class="form-control" value=pm_ratio}}


    <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'addSection'}}>Add Section</button>
    <div></div>
    {{#each section in sections}}
    <caption>{{section.sectionTitle}}</caption>
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=section.sectionTitle}}
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{#each item in section.items}}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{input type="text" value=item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{input type="text" value=item.hours}}</td>
            <td>{{getTotal}}</td>

            <td><button {{action 'removeItem' section item}}>Remove Item</button></td>
            {{/each}}
            <td><button {{action 'addItem' section}}>Add Item</button></td>                
            <td>{{totalHours}}</td>
            <td>{{totalCost}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {{/each}}
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `quote` as the model for your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing in your case might just be to write a helper as in:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('calculateRate', function(rate, hours) {
  return rate * hours;
});
```

See full example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gubaqavoso/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine your problem is that you're creating an observer, not a computed property. You have the following code:

```
getTotal: function(item) {
    return this.get('rate') * this.get('item.hours')
}.observes('rate', 'item.hours')
```

That is going to multiply those numbers together, but Ember isn't going to do anything with the result. (It expects observes to have side effects, not return values.) Trying to use it in a template would probably produce something like `[Object object]`. You need to change `observes` to `property`.

```
getTotal: function(item) {
    return this.get('rate') * this.get('item.hours')
}.property('rate', 'item.hours')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it still doesn't work. I think that using computed properties is correct, but the problem may be what properties I'm using.

Comment: It might help if you tell us exactly what isn't working. You've told us what you expect, but not what you're actually seeing.

Comment: Presently, I'm just seeing an empty total box. I believe the issue deals with the item.hours'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice before, but `item` is not a property on your controller, it's a function parameter. Try either `item.get('hours')` or `Ember.get(item, 'hours')`.

Comment: item.get('hours') - returns a error message: function is undefined.

Comment: Ember.get(item, 'hours') returns the template, but the total box says NAN.

Comment: Then you should put a breakpoint in that property and inspect those values and see what's going on. More likely than not one of the values is undefined.